# Can a defense attorney switch the defendants in court?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, criminal-procedure

Can a defense attorney switch the defendant in court to prove that a witness can't recognize him? (Like [Saul Goodman did.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvkYRhu-TP0)) What would be the consequences?